# Why does printf not print after running the png_read_png function?

Tags: c, printf, libpng

Platform=**Win10x64** Compiler=**GCC** Lang=**C** Lib=**libpng16.dll**

I'm trying to use the libpng library, but printf outputs nothing after this line:

```
  png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <png.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("starting...\n");
  
  FILE *fp = fopen("test.png", "rb");
  if (!fp) {
    printf("error #%d\n", 1);
  }  

  // Read the PNG header
  png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (!png_ptr) {
    printf("error #%d\n", 2);
  }

  // create stuct for png info/meta data
  png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
  
  if (!info_ptr) {
    printf("error #%d\n", 3);
  }

  if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
    printf("error #%d\n", 4);
  }    

  png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

  // Read the PNG image data
  printf("before printf dies\n");
  png_read_png(png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY, NULL);
  printf("this will not print after png_read_png is ran\n");
  fflush(stdout);

/* it won't print regardless if the below cleanup code is commented out or not */

  // Get the image dimensions and bit depth
  png_uint_32 width, height;
  int bit_depth, color_type;
  png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &width, &height, &bit_depth, &color_type, NULL, NULL, NULL);


  // Allocate memory for the image data
  png_bytep *row_pointers = png_malloc(png_ptr, height * sizeof(png_bytep));
  for (png_uint_32 i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
      row_pointers[i] = png_malloc(png_ptr, png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr));
  }

  // Read the image data into memory
  png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

  // Clean up
  png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
  
  // Free the memory allocated for the image data
  for (png_uint_32 i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {
      png_free(png_ptr, row_pointers[i]);
  }
  png_free(png_ptr, row_pointers);
/**/

  fclose(fp);
  
    return 0;
}
```

It will output this:

```
starting...
before printf dies
```

Sorry for the newb question. But I can't find any information on this. Just a bunch of posts saying to end printf with a newline, but I am doing that. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: start the debugger. single step until where you call this function. Check that all your inputs look as you think they should. Step over the library call. Check if all outputs are as you expect them to be and look out of crashes.

Comment: @Simson Thanks, I am learning how to do that. It seems you compile with -g option then run "gdb prog_name". It appears "s" is the step command, but I get "The program is not being run." from the console, so I'm guessing there's a special command to pause before the prog ends, but still looking.

Comment: I have no idea how this is meant to work, but I ran it on Linux with gdb. When you call png_read_image() it longjmps back to the setjmp address, and basically enters an infinite loop. Logging: error #4 / before printf dies / libpng error: Read Error. If setjmp() returns non-zero, you need to exit() or return. You have a lot of error checks that log something but carry on regardless.

Comment: The line gets printed for me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for why your code appears to lock up and not progress is because you are misunderstanding what setjmp() returns. You seem to think it returns 0 for success, and !0 for an "error".

This not correct. It returns 0 for when you actually call setjmp(), and !0 for when some other code calls longjmp() and returns you to there.

png_read_image() seems to be (for some reason) calling jongjmp() to signal an error. So your code enters an infinite loop.

All of your tests for errors should not just log the error then continue with the program. They should exit() or return.

There is obviously some other problem (why png_read_image() is failing), but this is the explanation for your current problem (code locks up).

Comment: On Windows the program does not lock up, it just appears to run and exit with no error. But thank you for the info, I will look into setjpm. Most of this code is copied from examples, so I also am not sure how setjpm is supposed to work. But I will try correctly trapping an error there.

Comment: All of your error checks should return or exit. Then you will see what the real problem is. I don't really get why libpng uses this weird mechanism to signal errors. It's very unusual.

Comment: I added return statements on all the errors, but behavior is the still the same. Of course it has to be this way, because the printf before png_read_png does execute and print "before printf dies". If any of the above error traps were hitting, those errors should be printed before that. Btw, I've learned setjpm is supposed to save the entire program state, and restore the state and continue running in the event of an error. That seems wild to me as well. But its the most popular PNG library, so I guess we don't know what we're missing.

Comment: None of them seem to be returning errors, but but you should still return. It's the setjmp() one - it does not return an error, it tells you if you have longjmp()ed to get there or not.  I'd just remove the setjmp stuff, and test the return values from png_init_io() and png_read_png().

Comment: Both of the functions seem to return void in the docs: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.init.io.1.html https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.read.png.1.html

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation, it appears that png_read_png was encountering an error that it could not report (even with setjmp and custom error trapping). The reason for this appears to be an incompatibility between the source code and the binary that was packaged with the source. So, there is currently no way to program with libpng with C on Windows 10 without compiling the libpng from src and creating your own binary, unless you can find a 3rd party who offers a Windows x64 binary with compatible source code.

To recap on why printf is not printing:

1. png_read_png encounters an unexpected situation due to unknown src/binary mismatch
2. png_read_png is unable to call a custom error handler and jumps to the setjpm point before png_read_png is called
3. png_read_png is called again and the cycle continues
4. Windows must somehow detect an endless loop and the program quietly exits, looking as if it finished without printing, but never actually reaching the lower printf statements
5. ???
6. Profit